# CSS: table {width:100%; display:block;} not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS: table {width:100%; display:block;} not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809804/css-table-width100-displayblock-not-working-in-firefox)

I have an html table within a div of a specific size.  I want the table to apply margin collapse and be 100% wide.  Here is my code.  It renders how I want it to in IE8 and incorrectly in Firefox.  Firefox may be doing the spec correctly, but whatever.  How do I fix my css to work in both browsers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>

<style type="text/css">
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table
{
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
}

td, th
{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width: 600px; border: 1px purple solid;">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Label 1</td>
        <td>1.A</td>
        <td>1.B</td>
        <td>1.c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Label 2</td>
        <td>2.A</td>
        <td>2.B</td>
        <td>2.c</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I need the `display:block` for margin collapsing to work in Firefox.