# Table overflows width of parent only in Firefox. Not caused by padding/margin/border

Tags: css, firefox, overflow, css-tables

I have a table that for some reason keeps overflowing the width of its container. Works fine in chrome, but in Firefox it just refuses.

Site can be found here: `http://goo. gl/vkN5s`

I've tried using `box-sizing: border-box;` (with -moz prefix) on the table, no difference (I also don't see why it would make a difference). The images in the table has some margin, but even after removing the margin it still overflows the container by at least 20px. The table has a width of 100% so it should fill the container. The td's have 50% width. 50% width is more than enough for the images to fit (even with the image margin).

I've read [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809804/css-table-width100-displayblock-not-working-in-firefox), most of which suggests removing padding/margin/border and not having `display: block;` (which i don't have). I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Why are you using a table for that layout?

Comment: I think it's the images' display inline and float properties combined with the margins that are causing the issues. I'd recommend getting rid of the table as tables are only meant to be used to display tabular data. A simple UL would probably do the job for you.

Comment: The table is just used for the images, i should have mentioned that. Also, i need to use some sort of grid layout (two column rows) because i need two images per row, and the images are responsive, so i can't just float them because they wouldn't scale on window resize then. It's all created through Wordpress, and it has to be easy for my client to do, so tables are the best solution for this if i can get it working. **Edit:** Even after removing the margin and setting the images to `display:block;` it still  overflows the container by 20 px, and that is super strange!

Answer (score 0):

if you use `border-collapse:collapse` remove it.